# Using JSSOR, trying to create a dynamic array of images to call from, not sure how to start

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, jssor

Being a novice programmer, I'm trying to create an JSSOR Slider to call from an array of images within a .aspx web page.  I'm familiar with Jquery, JavaScript, Bootstrap, HTML and anything else that may be relevant, but I'm at a loss on how to go about doing this.

Relevant parts of my html document:

```
asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageBody" runat="server" onLoad ="initiliaze()">
<div style="height:500px; margin:0 auto; display:block;">
    <div align:"center" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-24 col-lg-offset-5">
            <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 480px;">
                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: relative; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 480px;">
                    <div> <img u ="image" src='../Resources/Images/NewMEOBannerV3_1050x150.png'/></div>
                    <div><img u ="image" src ="</div>
                    <div> <img u="image" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/CINA288fZUs/maxresdefault.jpg" /> </div>
                    <div> <img u="image" src="http://edge.alluremedia.com.au/m/k/2015/06/arkham1.jpg" /> </div>
                    <div> <img u="image" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VpXUIh7rlWI/maxresdefault.jpg" /> </div>
                </div>
                <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="bottom: 0px; right: 0px;">
                    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top: -250px; left: -450px;"></span>
                    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top: -250px; right: -450px;"></span>
                    <div u="prototype"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div style="line-height:75%;">
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="ticker1">
                    <div class="innerWrap">
                        <div class="list"> This is content</div>
                        <div class="list"> This is also content </div>
                        <div class="list"> Still content here...</div>
                        <div class="list"> YES THIS IS CONTENT. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to put the images that are in the slider div into an array and then call the array later to consolidate everything and make it easy for backend editing.

Comment: As you may know, an aspx page can contain plain old html, css and javascript just like any other html page. Considering you mention you are familiar with all required technologies, can you provide us with a sample on what you have achieved in html, so we can help you pinpoint the problem and help you with the asp.net part?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

To crate jssor slider dynamically, you can fill html code dynamically, and then initialize jssor slider after that.

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        //define image array
        var images = [
            "../img/landscape/01.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/02.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/03.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/04.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/05.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/06.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/07.jpg",
            "../img/landscape/08.jpg"
        ];

        //retrieve the 'slides' container element to fill slides.
        var slidesElement = document.getElementById("slides");

        //fill images dynamically
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var slideElement = document.createElement("div");
            var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
            imgElement.setAttribute("u", "image");
            imgElement.src = images[i];
            slideElement.appendChild(imgElement);
            slidesElement.appendChild(slideElement);
        }

        var options = {};

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    });
</script>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
    height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div id="slides" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- dynamically fill slides here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the syntax I would use for that? Could you give an example? I know it's basic, but I'm just blanking on it